# Proper index for MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a simple table structure which becomes obvious from the following query:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.reserved_until < 1520028463911
  AND j.scheduled_time < 1520024838836
  AND j.retries < 5
  AND j.active = 1
LIMIT 1000
```

I'm using this query as a part of update to exclude the chance of race conditions and reserve some jobs

```
UPDATE jobs AS j
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT j.job_id
    FROM jobs j
    WHERE j.active = 1
      AND j.scheduled_time < :now
      AND reserved_until < :now
      AND j.retries < :max_retries
    ORDER BY j.scheduled_time
    LIMIT :count
) S ON j.job_id = S.job_id
SET
    j.reserved_by = :reserved_by,
    j.reserved_until = :reserved_until
```

But when I run explain over select which I've described above, it gives me very high cost for this query. What I did is I tried to create an index that would reduce the cost of the query. I've tried different combinations of indexes and I've created a compound index for fields `(reserved_until, scheduled_time, retries, active)` but it gives no improvement. What am I doing wrong, to my understanding this select should just pick 1000 from an index I've provided?

Thank you in advance!

*EDIT*

Here is the result of explain:

```
id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'j', NULL, 'range', 'jobs_retries,jobs_scheduled_time,jobs_reserved_until', 'jobs_retries', '4', NULL, '254466', '2.50', 'Using index condition; Using where'
```

[image]

*EDIT*

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `job_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `scheduled_time` double NOT NULL,
  `reserved_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reserved_until` double NOT NULL,
  `external_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `retries` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `jobs_url` (`url`),
  KEY `jobs_reserved_by` (`reserved_by`),
  KEY `jobs_external_id` (`external_id`),
  KEY `jobs_retries` (`retries`),
  KEY `jobs_scheduled_time` (`scheduled_time`),
  KEY `jobs_reserved_until` (`reserved_until`),
  CONSTRAINT `jobs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `job_types` (`job_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=509135 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Another edit**

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  j   NULL    range   jobs_retries,jobs_scheduled_time,jobs_reserved_until,jobs_another_index jobs_retries    4   NULL    252116  2.5 Using index condition; Using where
```

**Another edit**

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  j   NULL    range   jobs_retries,jobs_scheduled_time,jobs_reserved_until,jobs_another_index jobs_retries    4   NULL    252116  2.5 Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: May I know is scheduled_time is one of the index? or you can add it then give a try? or change the compound index to (scheduled_time, reserved_until, retries, active) [scheduled_time must be at first one, because you order by scheduled_time].

Comment: I can do anything, should I remove all indexes first?

Comment: When you ask for help with query optimization, please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE jobs` (or whatever tables are referenced by your query) and include the output. Everyone will need to know what indexes you already have, as well as data types, constraints. Help us help you!

Comment: @Sphinx, I have created the index, query cost reduced twice but it's still 200 000...

Comment: @Lu4 Can you post out new explain result?

Comment: But I've did, it's under last "Another edit"

Comment: @Sphinx I just need first 1000 rows, did I mistakenly asked for a shift by a 1000 items?

Comment: @Lu4 Sorry, I messed up my mind. check avoid full table scan which provides three solutions for large tables --you can try FORCE INDEX first, It seems mysql doesn't use your indexes due to `You are comparing indexed columns with constant values and MySQL has calculated (based on the index tree) that the constants cover too large a part of the table and that a table scan would be faster.` .

Comment: The inconsistency in the times is bothering me.  The `SELECT` has two different times, about 1 hour apart; the `UPDATE` shows the same time (`:now`).  Which is realistic?  I ask because I want to present a technique that involves understanding the relationship between those columns.  Is `scheduled_time` necessarily less than `reserved_until`?

Comment: Essentially, you cannot avoid a table (or index) scan with the structure as you have it.

Comment: Also, do the "jobs" get deleted?  Or are there a lot of old records cluttering the table?  If so, is there some high-water mark that we can use as a lower bound?